# How Get Data from a WEB with simple Login? No pass

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, get

How is possible to automate get this data in python or some webscraping
The page is the next, the loggin is simple, without password:

http://web.directemar.cl/pago_bci/boton_pago.html

rut: 82728500-5

And then go to this page:

https://bel.bci.cl/cl/bci/aplicaciones/directemar/vistas/vistaInicio.jsf

[VIEW OF THE WEBPAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6iQD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use selenium library and bs4. You can easily paste your password and press buttons in the web-page with functions like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.get("http://web.directemar.cl/pago_bci/boton_pago.html")
button = driver.find_element_by_id('YourElement')
button.click()
```

Comment: thanks for the help!! thats what im looking for

Comment: @salem1992 you can vote for my answer if it helped you. Thanks in advance)